# Add News using NewsApi Flutter

Tags: flutter, function, feed, google-news

So i am building a news page for my app , but i am unable to add news using the news api i have made the function that extracts and adds News to the BreakingNews ( basically the headlines ) and the RecentNews Lists

```
import 'package:vitactivity/models/News.dart';

class ArticleModel {
  String? title;
  String? author;
  String? content;
  String? urlToImage;
  String? date;
  String url;

  //let's create the constructor
  ArticleModel(this.title, this.author, this.content, this.date,
      this.urlToImage, this.url);

  static List<ArticleModel> breakingNews = [...]; // i have some dummy data here
  static List<ArticleModel> recentNews = [...]; // i have some dummy data here
}
```

i have written the other function that extracts and adds data to the list until a desired length is achieved but i cant figure out how do i call this function correctly so i can actually have the news added ( i am probably very dumb )

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:vitactivity/models/ArticleModel.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class News {
  Future<void> getNews(int a) async {
    while (ArticleModel.breakingNews.length <= a) {
      String url =
          "http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&catagory=health&sortBy=publishedAt&language=en&apiKey=Apikey"; // using the correct api key and gives me results on chrome as well

      var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

      var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);

      if (jsonData['status'] == "ok") {
        jsonData["articles"].forEach((element) {
          if (element['urlToImage'] != null && element['description'] != null) {
            ArticleModel article = ArticleModel(
              element['title'],
              element['author'],
              //element['description'],
              element['urlToImage'],
              element['publishedAt'],
              element["content"],
              element["url"],
            );
            ArticleModel.breakingNews.add(article);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[The Ui with the Dummy works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzyWQ.jpg)

i have tried to write the function that calls the getNews function but everything is giving me errors and cant even find anything on the internet , every thing seems very complex to figure out on my own without the documentation

i wrote this inti function to get the the news added but nothing is happening

```
void initState() {
News().getBreakingNews(5);
News().getRecentNews(10);
super.initState();
```

}

Comment: while (ArticleModel.breakingNews.length == a), maybe the problem lies here in this line of code, assume your breakingNews length is zero and a is 5 ( like you passed in the function call), the  While condition is always not match and it just no run into your while function code hen no api call. Try to change to  while (ArticleModel.breakingNews.length < a)

Comment: Agree with Đức Thành Lê. The issue is in the logic itself

Comment: oh i already have fixed that one in the actual code , but i guess the issue is with how i am calling the functions i am trying some different methods placing it in different places hopefully it will work